# Getting Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, server, gps

I am trying to read data sent by the GPS device to m server. I have a VPS server with static IP address. I am getting error (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host c#) to read data.

My GPS device sending data to static IP provided by the hosting and port 80.

With the below code, I am doing both sending and reading the data.

For the time being, I want to read data on click of "button" on the web page.

Here is the code:

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    string message = "Thisistestmessage";
    Int32 port = Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text);
    //string server = "127.0.0.1";
    string server = "45.58.143.201";
    string content = "";
    byte[] dataa = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse(server);
    IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, port);
    Socket s = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    s.Connect(ip);
    Response.Write("Socket Connected");
    s.Send(dataa);
    Response.Write("Message Sent");
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    int i = s.Receive(data);
    Response.Write("Data received");
    Response.Write(i.ToString());
    //Response.ContentEncoding(i.ToString());
    //Response.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
    s.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: A connection has 3 properties 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  You can only have one connection on a machine with all three the same.  So when you have the server and client on the same machine you get the error you are seeing.  To solve the issue the Listener (Server) should use IPAny :  IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Any;  You also get error is the client uses the loopback IP 127.0.0.1.  You have the loopback commented out which confuses my.  Are you getting the error posted with 45.58.143.201?  Try pinging address and see if you get a response.

Comment: Yes, I am using the error posted with 45.58143.201. Also, my main concern is to read data on the port send by the GPS device

Comment: The error is probably due to a route not existing to device.  I would start by using from cmd.exe > Ping 45.58.143.201 and see if you get a response.  So either the route is not configured probably to handle the IP address or you PC is not configured probably.  You can get the IP address and mask using from cmd.exe >IPConfig/all and check if the combination of IP and mask allows IP address 45.58.143.201 to pass.

Comment: Normally you want to use an IP address inside your network.  You also want to make sure that nothing else is using the IP.  So with device off make sure you ping IP to make sure nothing else on network response to the address before assigning.  You also want to make sure the port number isn't blocked by a virus checker or firewall.  And finally make sure any routers you have allow the IP address to pass.

Comment: I am running this code on a web server. I have created a web page for the same. Here is the link of web page: http://priyankaarwal-001-site1.htempurl.com/test2/Default.aspx (textbox for port and button "Send and receive data")

Comment: Do not use the loopback address 127.0.0.1,  Instead use the IP address or name of GPS device.  The port number should be the one that is set in GPS Device.  Can you ping the device?  You MUST get ping working first.  How are you connected to GPS Device.  Direct or through a hub.  If you are directly connect you must use a Ethernet Cross-Over Cable.  A normal Ethernet when you look at the wire in the connector at end of cable they are straight.  A Cross-Over one end of cable has two wire crossed.  When you go though a hub or router you use a straight cable.